# USB Programming Tutorial

Tags: c, embedded, usb

I was trying to program a USB2 controller(EHCI) on a bare metal system(No OS,No drivers). Are there any USB tutorial available for an absolute beginner ? The EHCI specs seemed to be too complex for a beginner.

Comment: If you are an absolute beginner and the EHCI specs are too complex for you, you shouldn't try to implement it, you will fail. Better try to use a stack from a free source

Comment: sometimes try+fail=learn, others learn+try=fail, though the gifted only seem to learn+try= expect understudy to fix.

Comment: Very true..I built a library from scratch. Just using USB2.0/EHCI  spec!

Comment: See also https://wiki.osdev.org/Universal_Serial_Bus

Answer (score 3):

[USB Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931448086) is a good book that will give you a start. Hard to find online tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Between that book mentioned and http://www.barebox.org/ . Writing (what I assume will be a host stack) from scratch will take a verrrry looooong timmmmme.

barebox is a multiplatform bootloader. pretty sparse for it's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar situation trying to write a USB driver for an embedded bare metal system. I have found the book "**USB: The Universal Serial Bus**" by **Benjamin David Lunt** to be a very useful tutorial on the subject. It covers writing bare metal firmware for UHCI, OHCI, EHCI and xHCI controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly your chipset is, [AMD documentation](http://developer.amd.com/assets/42413_sb7xx_rpr_pub_1.00.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Some nutter on the Freescale forums writing one in assembler, you may find some pointers there: [USB Stack in assembler - mad or genius?](http://forums.freescale.com/t5/68K-ColdFire-reg-Microprocessors/Writing-a-USB-device-in-assembly-Crazy-or-doable/td-p/91153)

Answer (score 0):

For AVR USB controllers there is a nice LUFA library with examples for many USB classes. There are also ports for other architectures such as NXP LPC.
http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php